# Java 8 : Stream.filter not running as expected

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, short-circuiting

Given:

```
    List<String> str = Arrays.asList ("my", "pen", "is", "your", "pen");
    Predicate<String> test = s -> {
        int i = 0;
        boolean result = s.contains ("pen");
        System.out.print((i++) + ":");
        return result;
    };
```

This prints: 0:0:

```
    str.stream().filter(test).findFirst();
```

And this prints 0:0:0:0:0:

```
    str.stream().filter(test).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

What confuses me is, no matter it is **findFirst** or **collect**, no matter the terminal operation is **short-circuiting** or not, they both should iterate through each item in the list, right?

So why "0:" is printed **twice**, not just **once**, not **5 times**, in the first example findFirst?

Comment: When the API reads "find first", why would you expect it to iterate further?

Comment: Your print of the count is using a post increment and will always be zero.

Answer (score 6):

> What confuses me is, no matter it is findFirst or collect, **no matter the terminal operation is short-circuiting or not**, they both should iterate through each item in the list, right?

Ability to return without examining the entire stream is **exactly** what makes an operation (like `findFirst`) short-circuiting.  See [Streams javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps).

Streams documentation actually makes no promises about how or whether your predicate will be evaluated.  It just guarantees that it will return the first element of the stream that matches the predicate.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of the first Stream is iterate to find the first occurrence of "pen", so the Predicate iterates the array until finds the first element which matches the condition of the filter. For that reason, you see only two "0:". [Official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps)